# How to correctly pass a Set as a parameter when calling a contract using Taquito?

Tags: taquito

I have a simple smart contract on the Tezos blockchain that contains a pair of a set of addresses and a counter in its storage. The contract has a single entrypoint that allows setting the storage to a given value:

```
{ parameter (pair (set %addresses address) (nat %counter)) ;
  storage (pair (set %addresses address) (nat %counter)) ;
  code { CAR ; NIL operation ; PAIR } }
```

I want to interact with this contract using @taquito. Here is my script:

```
import { TezosToolkit } from '@taquito/taquito';
import { InMemorySigner } from '@taquito/signer';
import dotenv from 'dotenv';


async function main() {
  dotenv.config();
  const Tezos = new TezosToolkit(process.env.RPC_NODE);
  const signer = await InMemorySigner.fromSecretKey(process.env.PRIVATE_KEY);
  Tezos.setProvider({ signer: signer });

  const account = await Tezos.signer.publicKeyHash();
  const contract = await Tezos.contract.at(process.env.CONTRACT_ADDRESS);
  const params = {
    'addresses': [account],
    'counter': 420
  };

  const operation = await contract.methods.default(params).send();
  await operation.confirmation();
}

main();
```

When I run the script, I get the following error: `SetValidationError(value, this, 'Value must be an array')`. Here is the full error stack:

```
/home/reproduce-taquito-set/node_modules/@taquito/michelson-encoder/dist/taquito-michelson-encoder.umd.js:2357
          return new SetValidationError(value, this, 'Value must be an array');
                 ^

SetValidationError: [addresses] Value must be an array
    at SetToken.isValid (/home/reproduce-taquito-set/node_modules/@taquito/michelson-encoder/dist/taquito-michelson-encoder.umd.js:2357:18)
    at SetToken.Encode (/home/reproduce-taquito-set/node_modules/@taquito/michelson-encoder/dist/taquito-michelson-encoder.umd.js:2361:28)
    at /home/reproduce-taquito-set/node_modules/@taquito/michelson-encoder/dist/taquito-michelson-encoder.umd.js:718:48
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at PairToken.Encode (/home/reproduce-taquito-set/node_modules/@taquito/michelson-encoder/dist/taquito-michelson-encoder.umd.js:718:35)
    at ParameterSchema.Encode (/home/reproduce-taquito-set/node_modules/@taquito/michelson-encoder/dist/taquito-michelson-encoder.umd.js:3805:32)
    at ContractMethod.toTransferParams (/home/reproduce-taquito-set/node_modules/@taquito/taquito/dist/taquito.umd.js:3090:48)
    at ContractMethod.send (/home/reproduce-taquito-set/node_modules/@taquito/taquito/dist/taquito.umd.js:3068:52)
    at main (file:///home/reproduce-taquito-set/interact.js:19:60)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5) {
  value: {
    addresses: [ 'tz1VSUr8wwNhLAzempoch5d6hLRiTh8Cjcjb' ],
    counter: 420
  },
  token: SetToken {
    val: {
      prim: 'set',
      args: [ { prim: 'address' } ],
      annots: [ '%addresses' ]
    },
    idx: 0,
    fac: [Function: createToken],
    createToken: [Function: createToken]
  }
}
```

It seems that I am not correctly constructing the set of addresses. How should I pass a set of addresses as a parameter when calling a contract using Taquito?

UPDATE: to simplify reproducing process I deployed this contract to [ghostnet](https://ghostnet.tzkt.io/KT1UYWUkUvcsYdiRoefuc9CageoqGRVvcXzP/operations/): KT1UYWUkUvcsYdiRoefuc9CageoqGRVvcXzP

UPDATE 2: here is github repo with this contract and script: https://github.com/ztepler/reproduce-taquito-set

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is, I believe, from how you are passing the params to the `contract.methods.default`
params should be passed as `contract.methods.default([address], 420)`

I hope this helps. Let me know if you need any other help!

other options is:

```
const operation = await contract.methodsObject.default({addresses: [account], counter: 420})
```

using `methodsObject` which will accept the object format

Comment: Wow, it really was that easy! Your suggestion with `methodsObject` works for both this dummy contract and the one I'm working with. Looks like I mixed up `methods` and `methodsObject`. Thanks you!

However this is strange that nothing is said about this `methodsObject` in the documentation, on those pages that I read:
[1] https://tezostaquito.io/docs/complex_parameters/
[2] https://tezostaquito.io/docs/quick_start/